# Painting issue with JLayer and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlayer

I want to paint an icon when user's input is invalid. I've found an example by Oracle and modified it for my purposes. The painting of Icon works correctly but when I change the value to correct the icon goes not completly invisible: the part which is drawn over the JPanel is still displayed.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class FieldValidator extends JPanel {
    private static final int ICON_SIZE = 12;
    private static final Icon ICON = createResizedIcon((ImageIcon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createUI() {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame ("FieldValidator");

        final JComponent content = createContent();

        f.add (content);

        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        f.setVisible (true);
    }

    private static JComponent createContent() {
        final LayerUI<JPanel> panelUI = new ValidationLayerUI();

        // Number field.
        final JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Number:");

        final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        final JFormattedTextField numberField = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormat) {
            /**
             * {@inheritDoc}
             */
            @Override
            public void replaceSelection(String content) {
                super.replaceSelection(content);
                getParent().repaint();
            }
        };
        numberField.setColumns(16);
        numberField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
        numberField.setValue(42);

        final int i = (ICON_SIZE / 2) + (ICON_SIZE % 2);
        final JPanel numberPanel = new JPanel();
        numberPanel.add(numberLabel);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final GridBagConstraints constr = new GridBagConstraints();
        constr.insets = new Insets(i, i, i, i);
        constr.weightx = 1;
        constr.weighty = 1;
        constr.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        panel.add(numberField, constr);
        numberPanel.add(new JLayer<JPanel>(panel, panelUI));

        return numberPanel;
    }

    //Icon resized to 12x12
    private static Icon createResizedIcon(ImageIcon anIcon) {
        final BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g.drawImage(anIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE, null);
        g.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(result);

    }
    static class ValidationLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {

        @Override
        public void paint (Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            super.paint (g, c);
            final JLayer jlayer = (JLayer) c;
            final JPanel panel = (JPanel) jlayer.getView();
            final JFormattedTextField ftf = (JFormattedTextField) panel.getComponent(0);
            if (!ftf.isEditValid()) {
                ICON.paintIcon(panel, g, 0, panel.getHeight() - ICON.getIconHeight());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the screens:
Initial all is correct

[image]

When I paint invalid Icon all is still correct

[image]

But when the value goes correct only the text field will be repainted

[image]

How can I force the JPanel to repaint???

P.S. I've already found an approach with JLayeredPane which works correct, but I want to know what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the `DocumentListener`:

```
numberField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //Container c = numberField.getParent();
    Container c = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(numberField);
    if (c != null) {
      c.repaint();
    }
  }
  @Override public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    insertUpdate(e);
  }
  @Override public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
});
```

#### Edit

Quote from this link: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

> The RepaintManager The purpose of Swing's RepaintManager class is to
>   maximize the **efficiency** of repaint processing on a Swing containment
>   hierarchy, and also to implement Swing's 'revalidation' mechanism (the
>   latter will be a subject for a separate article). It implements the
>   repaint mechanism by intercepting all repaint requests on Swing
>   components (so they are no longer processed by the AWT) and
>   maintaining its own state on what needs to be updated (known as "dirty
>   regions"). Finally, it uses invokeLater() to process the pending
>   requests on the event dispatching thread, as described in the section
>   on "Repaint Processing" (option B).

In this case the parent `JPanel` is not dirty region when `isEditValid()` status changed. so remaining previous `Icon` paint.

Comment: @aterai please for why reason you call updateUI/repaint() in code examples about JLayer, really isn't possible to notify container (painter) about painting changes

Comment: Thank you for solution. The question is: why it works with document listener but not in replaceSelection???

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy `JTextComponent#replaceSelection(...)` is not called a portion of the text has been removed.

Comment: @aterai strange but you are right. I was sure that it also called on deletion with empty string. Mea maxima culpa :)